# ¿Cómo agregar datos a un objeto en la celda de la fila correspondiente?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-html-service

Estoy realizando un código en el cual al encontrar una condición envíe un correo, pero requiero que después de que se envió agregue en la celda AE un "Sí", gracias a la respuesta de otra pregunta logre agregar el "Sí" sin embargo no lo coloca en la fila correspondiente a los datos, lo esta agregando fila 1 y borra el titulo de la columna y si tengo más datos, el "Sí" del siguiente valor lo coloca en la fila 11 y así va avanzando de 10 en 10.

Este es el código:

```
function rev_correo() {
  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const hoja = libro.getSheetByName("Info");
  const filas = hoja.getRange("A2:AE").getValues();

    for (indiceFila in filas) {
      var revision = crearRevision(filas[indiceFila]);
      revisionCorreo(revision,hoja,indiceFila +1);
    }
  }
 
function crearRevision(datosFila) {
  const revision = {
    folio: datosFila[0],
    valor1: datosFila[3],
    valor2: datosFila[6],
    icmail: datosFila[27],
    immail: datosFila[28],
    gcmail: datosFila[29],
    comentario: datosFila[22],
    estatus: datosFila[24],
    correo: datosFila[30],
  };
    
  return revision;
}
 
function revisionCorreo(revision, hoja, filas){
  const plantilla = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Formato Revisión');
  plantilla.revision = revision;
  const mensaje = plantilla.evaluate().getContent();

    if(revision.estatus == "Rechazado" && revision.correo== ""){   
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: revision.icmail +","+ revision.immail,
      cc: revision.gcmail,
      subject: "Rechazado",
      htmlBody: mensaje,
      });

    hoja.getRange(fila,31).setValue("Sí");
    }

}
```

Intente tambien en lugar de:

```
hoja.getRange(fila,31).setValue("Sí");
```

como:

```
hoja.getRange(indiceFila + 1,31).setValue("Sí");
```

pero tampoco tuve éxito.
Entiendo que es por que *fila* o *indiceFila* no hacen referencia a la fila donde estan los datos. Pero no los logro referenciar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué documentación estás utilizando para manipular las hojas de calculo?

Comment: para ingresar un valor "si" en la columna AE  usa de esta forma hoja.getRange( "AE" + (indiceFila+1) ).setValue("Sí");

Comment: Documentación setValue()  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=es#setValue(Object)

Comment: @PatrickArguello ya lo probé como mencionas y sigue poniendo los valores en las celdas AE1, AE11 y AE21

Answer (score 0):

El problema que encontre es con esta instruccion "indiceFila +1":

```
 for (indiceFila in filas) {
    var revision = crearRevision(filas[indiceFila]);
    // revisionCorreo(revision,hoja,indiceFila +1);  ** indiceFila +1 esta concatenando los valores **
    revisionCorreo(revision,hoja, Number(indiceFila) +1);  // con Number() convertimos indiceFila a numero antes de hacer la adicion
 }
```

// luego de enviar el correo inserta el valor si en la columna AE

```
  function revisionCorreo(revision, hoja, filas){
     ...

     hoja.getRange('AE'+ filas).setValue("Sí"); // filas es el tercer parametro recibido en la function

}
```